# pdo prepare and execute in "one shot"?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, query-performance

I am executing a lot of times a prepared statement. Here is my code below :

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8';
        $user = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $options = [];

        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);

        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user(name, surname, birthDate) VALUES (:name, :surname, :birthDate)");

        for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ )
        {
            $stmt->execute([
                ':name' => 'Doe',
                ':surname' => 'John',
                ':birthDate' => '1970-01-01'
            ]);
        }

        $stmt = null;

        $pdo->commit();

        $pdo = null;
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        die( $e->getMessage() );
    }
?>
```

This code will loop 1 000 000 times and insert the user in the database.

What I have understand is that PDO will constantly make goings and coming between the server and the database to perform these 1 000 000 executions.

I find it really heavy when it comes to deal with thousands of rows. So I've made something on my own using regular `PDO::query()` method instead of prepared statement, and here is how it looks like :

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8';
        $user = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $options = [];

        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);

        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        $queries = 'INSERT INTO user(name, surname, birthDate) VALUES ';        

        for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ )
        {
            $queries .= "('Doe, 'John', '1970-01-01'),";
        }

        $queries = rtrim( $queries, ',' );
        $queries .= ";";

        $pdo->query( $queries );

        $pdo->commit();

        $pdo = null;
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        die( $e->getMessage() );
    }
?>
```

This script above compact all the necessary queries and send them to the database in "one shot".

**Question**

Can we do the same but with prepared statement ? This would be so much handy to be able to send executed statement in one shot as the prepared query are WAY better in term of security (if I go with the query method I will have to escape manually my parameters...).

Obviously, this would make the query faster.

Comment: if you do `$queries .= "(?,?,?)"`; then bind each parameter ( 3 000 000 of them) individually you should be able to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @this.lau_ yes indeed, for the record, in my office we were inserting 1 300 000 rows (=database backup script). We had a ping of 3000ms, and with prepared statement it tooks 43mins. When we changed to regular query in "one shot" it tooks less than 3 mins.

Comment: @apokryfos Some good idea of improvement for PDO isn't it !

Comment: There are better tools available for database backups than simply copying rows. But if you used named parameters like `':name' . $i` you could also make it work; you just need to build a very big array and sql statement. Batches seem a better idea than millions at once though...

Comment: @jeroen we copy an HyperFile SQL to a MySQL database that is why we do this way. Obivoulsy if it was from MySQL to MySQL I would export the rows.

Comment: I have a feeling that a prepared statement, used in this way, will actually be slower. It has to bind all the data, whereas a direct query doesn't have to do this. And even if it isn't slower, it certainly won't be much faster... still I am curious to see the results. (The answer is: 'Yes, you can do this with a prepared statement'.)